# How to use a StaticResource Brush's Color?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I have a brush as a Resource:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

and I want to use it's `Color`:

```
<... BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBrush.Color}"/>
```

But it isn't possible and I get a xaml corruption error. How can I do that?

or in other away how to use Brush's `Color` in another `Color` resource:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="AppColor">#FFFFFF { here how to use AppBrush.Color?}</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: what error do you get? why simply not: <... Background="{StaticResource AppBrush}"/> ?

Comment: because that `BackgroundColor` is of type `Color` and doesn't accept `SolidColorBrush`

Comment: so @Gusdor's answer may help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
BackgroundColor="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource AppBrush}}"
```

This will only work if `AppBrush` is a `SolidColorBrush`.

Answer (score 7):

it's even easier:

```
BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBrush}"
```

or try this

```
<Application.Resources>
<Color x:Key="AppColor">#FFFFFF</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBrush" Color="{StaticResource AppColor}"/
</Application.Resources>
```